# Cannot get ObjectInputStream to work

Tags: java, sockets, stream, network-programming

I am currently trying to get my server to create a connection with a client. I have created a thread for each connection but the server is currently not creating the Input Stream. I have tested this by printing out numbers but only 1 and 2 get printed out. Im sure this is just a small problem that im missing.

```
public class ObjectHandler implements Runnable{
    Socket sock;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ObjectOutputStream oops;
    InputStream is;


    public ObjectHandler(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("1");
        sock = clientSocket;

        is = sock.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("2");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        System.out.println("3");

        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

        oops = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
        outputSockets.add(oops);    

    }
```

I have now removed the throws IOException and surrounded the reader with a try catch. After the client has crashed it now prints this error:

```
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2280)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2749)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:779)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)
at ThreadPool$ObjectHandler.<init>(ThreadPool.java:95)
at ThreadPool.addThread(ThreadPool.java:31)
at ObjectServerTest.go(ObjectServerTest.java:93)
at ObjectServerTest.main(ObjectServerTest.java:124)
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  Can you give us the stack trace?

Comment: That's only part of the stack trace.  We need to see all of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When constructing Object streams over sockets, you *always* need to construct the output stream *first* and *flush* it before creating the input stream (due to how the streams are implemented).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `BufferedInputStream`. You do not need it. It is waiting until 4K bytes are read.

Edit:
remove `BufferedOutputStream` too. 
And make sure that you are flushing the output stream on client side.

Comment: Creating a buffered input stream does not trigger a read. And more to the point, reading from a buffered input stream does not require 4k bytes of data to be read before returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

ObjectHandler:

```
public ObjectHandler(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("1");
    sock = clientSocket;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        is = sock.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("2");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        System.out.println("3"+ois.readFloat());

        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();

        oops = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os)); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 8888);
    OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
    oos.writeFloat(new Float(10.10));
    oos.flush();
}
```